# Preserve GitHub Pages URL when transferring ownership to an organization

Tags: github, github-pages

## Scenario

---

Suppose I have a [GitHub Pages](https://pages.github.com/) website. The repo is

```
https://github.com/username/username.github.io
```

and the website goes live at

```
https://username.github.io
```

But suppose I transfer the `username.github.io` repo to a [Github Organization](https://help.github.com/articles/about-organizations/). The repo URL changes to

```
https://github.com/organization/username.github.io
```

which is fine. But now, the website goes live at

```
https://organization.github.io/username.github.io
```

or just

```
https://organization.github.io/username
```

## Question

---

**How do I retain the `https://username.github.io` URL and still let the organization keep ownership?**

Comment: have you tried: https://help.github.com/articles/quick-start-setting-up-a-custom-domain/? Basically adding the `https://organization.github.io/username` as a custom domain in your project within the organization.

Comment: @Lucas good thought. In my case, though, doing that for every project would be a pain. Custom domains in general are turning out to be too much trouble.